# Laravel How to get `->sum('count')` in `whereHas` subquery?

Tags: laravel, eloquent

I have 3 model `Transaction` , `Cart` , `Acceptedcart`.

in `Cart` model I have `transaction_id` and in `Acceptedcart` model have `cart_id`.

in `Transaction.php` my relationship to carts:

```
public function carts()
{
    return $this->hasMany(Cart::class);
}
```

in `Cart.php` my relationship to accepted carts :

```
public function accepted_carts()
{
    return $this->hasMany(Acceptedcart::class);
}
```

And the query to get the transactions where `acceptedcart->sended== false`:

```
$transactions = Transaction::whereHas('carts.accepted_carts', function ($query) {
    $query->where('sended', false);
})->get();
```

Now I want to get `sum()` of count column in acceptedcart, where I can set the `sum()`?

```
$transactions = Transaction::whereHas('carts.accepted_carts', function ($query) {
    $query->where('sended', false);
})->sum('count);
```

Or

```
$transactions = Transaction::whereHas('carts.accepted_carts', function ($query) {
    $query->where('sended', false)->sum('count');
})->get();
```

is there Only one way that foreach on the `->get()` result ?

Answer (score 0):

Try this

**Transaction.php**

```
public function accepted_carts()
{
    return $this->hasManyThrough(Acceptedcart::class, Cart::class);
}
```

**Query**

```
$transactions = Transaction::query()
    ->whereHas('accepted_carts', fn ($query) => $query->where('sended', false))
    ->withCount([
        'accepted_carts' => fn ($query) => $query->select(DB::raw('SUM(count) as accepted_carts_sum'))
    ])
    ->get();
```